# Create efficient week over week calculation with subsetting

Tags: r, performance, loops, subset

In my working dataset, I'm trying to calculate week-over-week values for the changes in wholesale and revenue.  The code seems to work, but my estimates show it'll take about 75hrs to run what is a seemingly simple calculation.  Below is the generic reproducible version which takes about 2m to run on this smaller dataset:

```
########################################################################################################################
# MAKE A GENERIC REPORDUCIBLE STACK OVERFLOW QUESTION
########################################################################################################################

# Create empty data frame of 26,000 observations  similar to my data, but populated with noise
exampleData <- data.frame(product = rep(LETTERS,1000),
                          wholesale = rnorm(1000*26), 
                          revenue = rnorm(1000*26))

# create a week_ending column which increases by one week with every set of 26 "products"
for(i in 1:nrow(exampleData)){
  exampleData$week_ending[i] <- as.Date("2016-09-04")+7*floor((i-1)/26)
}
exampleData$week_ending <- as.Date(exampleData$week_ending, origin = "1970-01-01")

# create empty columns to fill
exampleData$wholesale_wow <- NA
exampleData$revenue_wow <- NA

# loop through the wholesale and revenue numbers and append the week-over-week changes
for(i in 1:nrow(exampleData)){
  # set a condition where the loop only appends the week-over-week values if it's not the first week
  if(exampleData$week_ending[i]!="2016-09-04"){
    # set temporary values for the current and past week's wholesale value
    currentWholesale <- exampleData$wholesale[i]
    lastWeekWholesale <- exampleData$wholesale[which(exampleData$product==exampleData$product[i] & 
                                                       exampleData$week_ending==exampleData$week_ending[i]-7)] 
    exampleData$wholesale_wow[i] <- currentWholesale/lastWeekWholesale -1

    # set temporary values for the current and past week's revenue
    currentRevenue <- exampleData$revenue[i]
    lastWeekRevenue <- exampleData$revenue[which(exampleData$product==exampleData$product[i] & 
                                                   exampleData$week_ending==exampleData$week_ending[i]-7)] 
    exampleData$revenue_wow[i] <- currentRevenue/lastWeekRevenue -1
  }
}
```

Any help understanding why this takes so long or how to cut down the time would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably not the main issue but... don't parse strings to dates in a loop; just save a `d0 = as.Date("2016-09-04")` somewhere and use that. Also don't `!=` vs a string that must be parsed to date. I suspect the main part of the code could be written as a merge/join instead of a loop.

Comment: This looks good and reproducible, but (at least in the future) I would suggest also making **minimal** examples. It would be much easier to inspect the data at each step to see what's happening with, say, 2 products and 4 weeks, than 26 products and 140 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I didn't want to oversimplify, but you're right in that it could have been more minimalistic. I'll keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: That's definitely the hard part - as minimal as possible but still illustrative of the problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first `for` loop can be simplified with the following for:

```
exampleData$week_ending2 <- as.Date("2016-09-04") + 7 * floor((seq_len(nrow(exampleData)) - 1) / 26)

setequal(exampleData$week_ending, exampleData$week_ending2)
[1] TRUE
```

Replacing second `for` loop

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- as.data.table(exampleData)
dt1[, wholesale_wow := wholesale / shift(wholesale) - 1 , by = product]
dt1[, revenue_wow := revenue / shift(revenue) - 1 , by = product]

setequal(exampleData, dt1)
[1] TRUE
```

This takes about 4 milliseconds to run on my laptop

Comment: Thanks, but the real trouble is with the second loop.  My real data didn't need to have a week-ending field added since it already existed so I just made that one up for the example.

Comment: @WillWright added code for second loop that executes in milliseconds

Comment: Incredible.  I don't think I've used the data.table package in the past, but I'll definitely be putting some time into learning it.  This solution works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized solution using the tidyr package.

```
set.seed(123)
# Create empty data frame of 26,000 observations  similar to my data, but populated with noise
exampleData <- data.frame(product = rep(LETTERS,1000),
                          wholesale = rnorm(1000*26), 
                          revenue = rnorm(1000*26))

# create a week_ending column which increases by one week with every set of 26 "products"
#vectorize the creating of the data
i<-1:nrow(exampleData)
exampleData$week_ending <- as.Date("2016-09-04")+7*floor((i-1)/26)

exampleData$week_ending <- as.Date(exampleData$week_ending, origin = "1970-01-01")

# create empty columns to fill
exampleData$wholesale_wow <- NA
exampleData$revenue_wow <- NA

#find the index of rows of interest (ie removing the first week)
i<-i[exampleData$week_ending!="2016-09-04"]

library(tidyr)

#create temp variables and convert into wide format
# the rows are product and the columns are the ending weeks
Wholesale<-exampleData[ ,c(1,2,4)]
Wholesale<-spread(Wholesale, week_ending, wholesale)

Revenue<-exampleData[ ,c(1,3,4)]
Revenue<-spread(Revenue, week_ending, revenue)

#number of columns
numCol<-ncol(Wholesale)

#remove the first two columns for current wholesale
#remove the first and last column for last week's wholesale
#perform calculation on ever element in dataframe (divide this week/lastweek)
Wholesale_wow<- Wholesale[ ,-c(1, 2)]/Wholesale[ ,-c(1, numCol)] - 1
#convert back to long format
Wholesale_wow<-gather(Wholesale_wow)

#repeat for revenue
Revenue_wow<- Revenue[ ,-c(1, 2)]/Revenue[ ,-c(1, numCol)] - 1
#convert back to long format
Revenue_wow<-gather(Revenue_wow)

#assemble calculated values back into the original dataframe
exampleData$wholesale_wow[i]<-Wholesale_wow$value
exampleData$revenue_wow[i]<-Revenue_wow$value
```

The strategy was to convert the original data into a wide format where the rows were the product id and the columns were the weeks.  Then divide the data frames by each other.  Convert back into a long format and add the newly calculated values to the exampleData data frame.  This works, not very clean but **very much faster** than the loop.  The dplyr package is another tool for this type of work.

To compare this results of this code with you test case use:

```
print(identical(goldendata, exampleData))
```

Where goldendata is your known good results, be sure to use the same random numbers with the set.seed() function.

Comment: Excellent! I knew the solution would likely be with restructuring the data, but I'm still new to thinking about solutions in these terms.  Thanks a ton! This runs in seconds. I'll definitely be adding this to my toolbelt.